# How to read data from file and store it in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

User will give me 2 rows which I have to add. Rows are linked lists. I want to read file and save each row content in linked list named as row. Then i want to add 2 rows of that file.

File is like

```
1 2 3 \n
5 5 5  \n
1 2 3  \n
```

```
void spreadsheet::add2()
{       
    int a, b = 0;   
    cout << "\nEnter Row 1 no : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout << "\nEnter Row 2 no: "; 
    cin>>b;    
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("ab.txt");
    row *temp = new row();
    row *temp1 = new row();
    for (int i = 0; i < a;i++)
    {
        if (fin)
        {
            while (fin >> temp->data )
            {
                temp->data = temp->next->data;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually creating a linked list? You have access to the STL; `std::list` should be sufficient for your purposes. Also, you haven't provided enough information for a [mcve].

Comment: So assuming all right with the world and your file opened successfully, you read into `temp->data` in your `while` condition, the immediately throw that data away by directly assigning with `temp->data = temp->next->data`. Call me skeptical, but  i don't think that's gonna work out so well. This code looks like you threw a handful of code at you assignment and hoped something would stick. I suggest reviewing your materials and trying again.

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file linked list"?